# restrict qualifier and pointer arithmetic

Tags: c++, c

Does incrementing or decrementing a restrict qualified pointer preserve no aliasing assumption?

```
// a and b point to disjoint arrays
void foo(size_t n, double * __restrict a, double * __restrict b) {
    size_t i;
    double x, y, z;
    double * c = b; // copy
    for(i=0; i<n; ++i) {
        x = *(a++);     // not aliased
        y = *(b + i);   // not aliased 
        z = c[i];       // not aliased
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: [mode pedantic] `restrict` is spelled without underscores in C99 since it is a language keyword. There is no such thing as `restrict` in the (any ?) C++ standard, although some implementations provide a replacement[/mode]

Comment: The __restrict qualifier is a not uncommon extension, supported in several C and C++ compilers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  The `restrict` qualifier is part of the type of the pointer, and this type isn't changed when you increment, decrement, or assign it.