# Does this violate the semantics of `restrict`?

Tags: c, restrict-qualifier

**NOTE** - This is very similar to [restrict qualifier and pointer arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6087160/6526693) , but is not a duplicate. The author of that post assigned the result of operations on a `restrict` pointer to the same pointer, while I assigned the result of operations on a `restrict` pointer as an argument to a `restrict` function parameter.

I understand the meaning of `restrict` for the most part, and I'm beginning to get in the habit of declaring function parameters `restrict` whenever applicable. But I'm unsure whether I'm abusing it here or not.

```
struct DynArray
{
    void* data;
    size_t elemCount;
    size_t len;
};

void dyn_append(DynArray* restrict dst, const void* restrict src, size_t srcLen, size_t elemSize)
{
    size_t oldElemCount = dst->elemCount;
    dyn_setElemCount(dst, dst->elemCount + srcLen, elemSize);    // might write to `*dst`
    if (dst->data)    // `dst->data` is set to `NULL` if reallocation fails.
        // The next line might violate "restrict-ness" of `dst`.
        memcpy((char*)dst->data + elemSize*oldElemCount, src, elemSize * srcLen);
}
```

Specifically, I'm referring to `(char*)dst->data + elemSize*oldElemCount` in the call to `memcpy`. If I had passed `dst` itself rather than the above argument, I know it would be valid, as I would be assigning it to a parameter of a function that is itself `restrict`. Does the fact that the argument is the result of operations on `dst` rather than `dst` itself change things in this case? My reasoning is that the guarantee that the argument won't be aliased is contained within the guarantee that `dst` won't be aliased.

Comment: This code does not assign to any of the function parameters. (Modifying data that a pointer points to, is different to assigning to the pointer)

Comment: `dyn_setElemCount` cannot write to `dst` because it is passed by value.  If you mean it writes to the memory that `dst` points to , then please update the question to say so.  As things stand the question is unclear.

Comment: The value of `dst->data` does not inherit the `restrict`-ness of `dst`

Comment: "Does the fact that the argument is the result of operations on dst rather than dst itself change things in this case?" Depends on if `src` overlaps `dst->data`.

Comment: @M.M I mixed up the local copy of the parameter when it's passed an argument with the parameter itself. Why I didn't just say "passed an argument to the parameter" is beyond me. And yes, I meant the data that it points to. I updated my post. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fine, but it doesn't really do anything because there's no time when aliasing the `dst` pointer would cause different behavior.

Comment: It makes a difference to `src` though since it is a `void*` it could point at anything.